# Xamarin forms, Using BottomNavigationBar makes calling OnAppearing twice

Tags: xamarin.forms, bottomnavigationview

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/thrive-now/BottomNavigationBarXF) to implement bottom navigation bar in android too (instead of old tablayout), the problem is calling `OnAppearing/Disappearing` is like so:

1. `OnAppearing`
2. `OnDisappearing`
3. `OnAppearing`

I call my `ViewModel`'s `LoadData()` method (that is responsible to fetch data from rest API and fill views) inside `OnAppearing` method, and as it's calling twice, the app is facing performance issue. Also as `OnDisappearing` is calling after first `OnAppearing` I cannot use a `bool` to handle when to call `LoadData()`. So how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

in Xamarin.Android if you override OnAppearing() in any page that gets pushed onto the navigation stack, irrespective of if it's the currently top most visible view that method will fire. you should add a check into OnAppearing() that your view is on top of the stack, if it isn't simply do nothing.

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        var Page = Navigation.NavigationStack.Last();

        if (Page.GetType() == typeof(NAMEOFPAGECLASSYOURON))
        {
           // Do what you want to do only if your on this page.
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was excited to try this way to simplify the role, but it does not working! in both times the if statement is `true`

Comment: Is there anything in ViewModel.LoadData(); that requires the current view to re-render itself?

Comment: Yes as user is able to go to inner views and change something that i'm showing at this page, I have to call `LoadData` inside `OnAppearing` like Android `onResume()`.

Comment: In that case theres a posibility that if your refreshing the view it'll recall onappearing. so what I'd perhaps suggest is a boolean check as well as the page type check (which is just good practice if you ask me.) so in your'e loaddata method set a boolean flag as true and call it something like "viewFirstRun" and do a check against it in your on appearing method inside of the if statement. that way the on appearing will only run your relevant code once, and only if it's the pages first time displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it is called twice but you can use the trick. Store timestamp of your OnAppearing in class variable. When OnAppearing is called check when last time it was called and if the time (lets say) less than 10 seconds don't do anthing